# jQuery BlockUI with many elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i know that we can block any element using jQuery BlockUI :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#blockButton2').click(function() { 
        $('div.test').block({ 
            message: '<h1>Processing</h1>', 
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

BUT , HOW to block many elements in the same time and action ?

Comment: Block the entire page? Not sure I get the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block as many elements as you need. Your code will work for all div elements with class text, not just a single one.

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9khTc/1/).

With this HTML markup:

```
<div class="block">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Second div</div>
<div class="block">Third div</div>
<input type="button" id="block" value="block" />
```

This script will block both first and third div at the same time:

```
$('#block').click(function() {
    $('div.block').block();
});​
```